# calling a constructor with no output

Tags: java, constructor, applet

I'm using OSGi/Felix in an applet, and when I try to make a new instant of 
 OperationSetBasicTelephonyJabberImpl with this code:

```
logger.info("***(ProtocolProviderServiceJabberImpl) arg: " + this);
        OperationSetBasicTelephonyJabberImpl basicTelephony = 
                new OperationSetBasicTelephonyJabberImpl(this);
```

The constructor doesn't get called, the first message in the constructor is not displayed,
it doesn't return any errors, just passing it. (they are in the same bundle)

The constructor:

```
public OperationSetBasicTelephonyJabberImpl(
        ProtocolProviderServiceJabberImpl protocolProvider) {
            //This line is not showing
    logger.info("(OperationSetBasicTelephonyJabberImpl)constructor started");
    this.protocolProvider = protocolProvider;
    this.protocolProvider.addRegistrationStateChangeListener(this);
    ChatPanel.protocolProvider = protocolProvider;
    logger.info("***********************************HELLO**************************");
}
```

I don't know why this is happening, what could be the problem?

Comment: is the logger for the package of OperationSetBasicTelephonyJabberImpl configured?

Comment: is the logger configured yet, when you call it inside the constructor? e.g. static logger

Comment: btw i suggest using interfaces as parameter types instead of their implementations

Comment: can you try BasicConfigurer.configure() into Constructor before log the constructor message?

Comment: yes the logger is enabled and works fine

Comment: the logger above the constructor prints everything, somehow when it calls the constructor it passes him and exiting the method ( this is inside a long method) and then continues

Comment: @Roman you mean if a service is miss configured it just skips the call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that Java wasn't throwing me an Error, Why I don't know.
I added this to the code:

```
try {
    OperationSetBasicTelephonyJabberImpl basicTelephony = 
                new OperationSetBasicTelephonyJabberImpl(this); 
} catch (Throwable t) {
    logger.info(t.getStackTrace());
} finally {
    // The rest...
}
```

And after that he threw me an error, However without the stack trace...

```
INFO: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jitsi/service/neomedia/event/SrtpListener
```

I don't have a clue why this happened as all my manifests and imports are correct, and this class is found in all the other code.